# Environment variable exported in shell in groovy function can not be used

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I defined a Jenkins declarative pipeline as below:

```
def test(String A){
    sh """
    export tag="20190101"
    echo "${tag}"
    echo "${A}"
    """
}
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('check'){
            steps{
                test("aaa")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I use `double quote` as below, the command `echo "${A}"` will cause an error:

```
sh """
    export tag="20190101"
    echo "${tag}"
    echo "${A}"
    """
```

error like this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: tag for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.test(WorkflowScript:4)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
    at 
....
```

So I changed the `double quote` to `single quote`, this time no error show, but I can get the variable pass from groovy, as below:

```
sh '''
    export tag="20190101"
    echo "${tag}"
    echo "${A}"
    '''
```

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (check)
[Pipeline] sh
+ export tag=20190101
+ echo 20190101
20190101
+ echo 

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I think if use `single quote`, environment variables can be parse correctly, variable pass from groovy can not be parsed; if use `double quote`, variable pass from groovy can be parse correctly, but environment variable in shell can't be parsed and an error will be caused.
However, I need to use variables both from shell environment which I set and pass from groovy, in my scenario, how to define the function with shell? Great thanks if you can help.

Note:

> Jenkins 2.x
>   Declarative pipeline.

Comment: sorry, in `double quote` scenario, the error should be caused by `echo "${tag}"`.

Comment: Did you try to use without double quote `echo ${tag}`?

Comment: In the double quoted solution, perhaps you need to escape the dollar sign to delay expansion: `echo "\$tag"`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def test(String A){
    sh """
    export tag="20190101"
    echo \$tag
    echo ${A}
    """
}
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('check'){
            steps{
                test("aaa")
            }
        }
    }
}
```